# Toggle Menu Button is Wrapped with a Link Tag

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming, togglebutton

I'm trying to remove the Link tag wrapped around my Navbar-Toggle because every time I try to expand the menu it redirects me.

The link needs to be removed, can someone guide me how? and why it got there in the first place?

I would appreciate your help :(

```
<a class="active" href="https://abalkhailrealestate.com/ar">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change the Link Tag "a" With "Div" Tag and Remove The href="" attribute If You Still Have That Problem Then Send Me You Whole Code I will Give it a Look!

Example:

```
<div>
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data- 
toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, looking back at this sure shows me how very enrty level I was.